# How to unlink autolinked bitbucket readme markdown

Tags: markdown, bitbucket, readme

BitBucket uses a MarkDown to render the 'index page' with the readme.md file which is in our repository.

There is a string in the readme.md file which looks like a commit hash 'a68c7c33f98668bea65636a7462a94f17446e151' but it isn't.

Now apperently bitbucket uses urlize (projekt from django) to autolink everything usefull in our readme.md.

This is useful for links but not when this hash, which is not a commit has, becomes a link to a commit which doesn't exist.

I'm looking now for a simple way to unlink this hash without marking it as sourcecode.

Anyone an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Offering a bounty isn't going to help much if other users can't understand what you're asking. You might do well to clarify your question.

Comment: @sigi, Chris is right. Give us more information about problem.

Comment: I rewrote the text, hopefully it is more clear. I might make a example project later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atlassian's documentation [specifies that 7-40 hex characters will be automatically linked](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Mark+up+comments#Markupcomments-LinkingtoBitbucketObjectsfromCommentsandCommitMessages).

You could prefix your hash with enough zeroes to surpass the 40 character threshold, e.g.

```
0a68c7c33f98668bea65636a7462a94f17446e151
```

or add a `0x` hexadecimal indicator, e.g.

```
0xa68c7c33f98668bea65636a7462a94f17446e151
```

to prevent the auto-linking.

Alternatively, you could insert a syntactically null value like `[]()` (an empty link) between every six hex characters, so each segment is below the seven character threshold:

```
a68c7c[]()33f986[]()68bea6[]()5636a7[]()462a94[]()f17446[]()e151
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in backticks as an inline code block. It is easily readable in the markdown and avoids the 6 empty anchor tags in the html. Those empty anchor tags break copy/paste in the editors I tried. Unfortunately it causes monospace formatting, so it is a trade-off.

```
`0xa68c7c33f98668bea65636a7462a94f17446e151`
```

Comment: I tired this, and it still auto-linked the text for me within the inline code block.