# Write a number in README.md on Bitbucket without a link to a commit

Tags: bitbucket, markdown, commit

If i write something like

```
## Test title
There are 1235467 users reading this on stackoverflow.
```

inside a README.md of a Bitbucket repo, 1234567 will be converted to a link. To be precise, it's converted to a link of a commit (apparently a number is recognized as a commit number). How can I disable this and let that number be a simple number?

Comment: This might be a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145878/how-to-unlink-autolinked-bitbucket-readme-markdown

Comment: @unflores i did a lot of research but i found nothing, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unlink autolinked bitbucket readme markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145878/how-to-unlink-autolinked-bitbucket-readme-markdown)